how do you put sets in a template tag?
ive tried [set]theset[set]. the tags are supposed to be replaced with greater than and equal signs I can see why that fails because set is also used to set a pattern. Ive tried [get name="set"]theset[/get]. that gives me an unknown wildcard.
Clearly it's just creating a variable set with a value the set. although that would work for a topic tag. [get name="topic"]thetopic[/get]. I don't think there's a way to do this in aiml which is fine. I know you can access sets through the pattern tag as [star index="1"/] [star index="2"/].
Technically I guess I can make a srai and put all the information in there with random tags but sets are so simple to use. they make life so much easier.
I expected it to fail. I put a [set]theset[/set] in a template tag and it failed. I tried multiple workarounds they all failed.

Sets go in patterns as you have seen. I can't think why you would want to put a set in a template, as sets are used to identify words with a common connection. You would access them by using star indexes in the template. What is it you are trying to achieve?
